# unable to get thymeleaf layout dialect example to work

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a springboot 1.5.9 project, which i am trying to get thymeleaf layout dialect templates working.

I am following the example given here

https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/Examples.html

I have created a Layout.html with the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
    <title>Layout page</title>
    <script src="common-script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>My website</h1>
</header>
<section layout:fragment="content">
    <p>Page content goes here</p>
</section>
<footer>
    <p>My footer</p>
    <p layout:fragment="custom-footer">Custom footer here</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and a content2.html with the following

```
<p layout:decorate="{Layout}" layout:fragment="custom-footer">
    My Custom Footer
</p>
```

my controller looks like

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public String intialiseService(Model model) {
    return "content2";
}
```

when I access root I get a page returned with just the html from content2.html

```
<p layout:decorate="{Layout}">
    My Custom Footer
</p>
```

I expect it to return the Layout.html with the footer modified to the content2.html contents

any suggestions gratefully accepted.

UPDATE
 I forgot to add my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.6.1" //rest api description
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.6.1' //rest api description ui
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.5') //to use cucumber
    testCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.5') //to run in junit via the ide
    testCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.2.5') //to use dependency injection
    acceptanceTestCompile('org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.6.RELEASE') //to run acceptance tests from feature file in IDE
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:${SCALA_VERSION}"
    loadTestCompile "io.gatling:gatling-http:${GATLING_VERSION}"
    loadTestCompile "io.gatling:gatling-core:${GATLING_VERSION}"
    loadTestCompile "io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:${GATLING_VERSION}"
    testCompile "io.gatling:gatling-app:${GATLING_VERSION}"
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-xml', version: '2.9.2'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile group: 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-layout-dialect', version: '1.1.3'
}
```

SECOND UPDATE:

THis got it working

https://progressive-code.com/post/14/Thymeleaf-Layout-Dialect-as-Decorator-Pattern-for-a-Spring-Boot-web-application

it looks like there is some syntax change so the docs I was using took me on the wrong path.

Comment: Did you add dependency for this dialect if you didin't add you can check [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.1.3)

Comment: I have tried that but I get the same result. I have updated my original post with my gradle dependancies

Answer (score 0):

replace following code in content2.html :
`<p layout:decorate="{Layout}" layout:fragment="custom-footer">
    My Custom Footer
</p>`

with this :

`<p layout:decorate="~{Layout}" layout:fragment="custom-footer">
    My Custom Footer
</p>`

I guess your missing `~` in front of the defined decorator.

Comment: can you try `Layout.html`

Comment: Same result again

Comment: Is Layout.html under the templates file if not your code should be following :
`<p layout:decorate="~{_DIRECTORYNAME_/Layout}" layout:fragment="custom-footer">
    My Custom Footer
</p>`